# Which comic book has this image of Wonder Woman carrying Superman and Batman?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, wonder-woman

After the success of *Wonder Woman* (2017) for DC Comics after *Dark Knight Rises* (2012), this picture is trending all over the Internet:

[image]

It indicates she saved last flop *Batman vs Superman* movie.

Which comic book does this image come from?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the meme appears to have been [created by the user @jarmainedesign](https://twitter.com/jermainedesign/status/865608087025135617) on Twitter. The original panel was taken from [*Trinity* #6](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/trinity-2016/trinity-6). Here is the full page, and the next one:

[image] [image]
 <sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

You can read a [preview on ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/articles/exclusive-preview-trinity-6/1100-156373/), and some [reviews here](http://comicbookroundup.com/comic-books/reviews/dc-comics/trinity-(2016)/6).

Comment: I tried searching but failed, anyway nice find

Comment: @covfefe I searched for "wonder woman I got it" and got this [KnowYourMeme page](http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1257201-wonder-woman), which listed the source on Twitter. I went there and got the original panel. Couldn't use reverse image search, so I searched for "white mercy" and learned it appeared in _Trinity_ #4. Then I simply looked at the issues until I found the correct one.

Comment: I have some access issues form office system, so was not able to search much in deep but I do wanted to know the answer for sure which you already given :)